# How to remove certain html tags from a String with replaceAll?

Tags: java, html, parsing, tags, replaceall

I have a string including different kinds of html tags.

I want to remove all `<a>` and `</a>` tags.

I tried:

```
string.replaceAll("<a>", "");
string.replaceAll("</a>", "");
```

But it doesn't work. Those tags still remain in the string. Why?

Comment: Strings are immutable; every operation that modify a String returns a String.

Comment: Don't use regex on HTML / XML. Also show us sample input

Comment: Better is to parse the html rather than removing tags using regex.

Comment: Actually for a replace, I would use regex here.. not every manipulation in HTML files on earth should use parsers.

Comment: When you were typing your question (and your 31 previous questions), there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right. Worth a read. There was also a full toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button with lots of helpful information. And a preview area under the text box. Most of these things were there when you were writing your five answers as well. Please take the time to learn to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Those tags still remain in the string. Why?

Because `replaceAll` doesn't modify the string directly (it can't, strings are immutable), it *returns* the modified string. So:

```
string = string.replaceAll("<a>", "");
string = string.replaceAll("</a>", "")
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/QGYKEh)

Or

```
string = string.replaceAll("<a>", "").replaceAll("</a>", "")
```

Note that [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes a string defining a regular expression as its first argument. `"<a>"` and `"</a>"` are both fine, but unless you need to use a regular expression, use [`replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead. If using `replaceAll`,  just be aware of the characters with special meaning in regular expressions.

In fact, you can do it with one `replaceAll` by making use of the fact you're using regular expressions:

```
string = string.replaceAll("</?a>", "");
```

The `?` after the `/` makes the `/` optional, so that'll replace `"<a>"` and `"</a>"`.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/I3GlV5)

Comment: Great and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll("\<\w*\>", "\ ").replaceAll("\", "\ ");  remove all tags html XD  , 2 "\"

Comment: or replaceAll("\\<(/?[^\\>]+)\\>", "\\ ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim()